# "Type DATE is not a defined system type."

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

My website working perfect on local, but not in host. 
I wrote my queries with MSSQL 2008 on local , but our hosting company using 2005
Any solutions?
EDIT : Using `DateTime` instead of `Date` looking like solution thanks.
If anyone meets a problem like this i solved my problem with using this query instead of DATE type.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),104) Output -> 15.03.2011
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Date columns aren't available in Sql Server 2005 so you have two choices:

1) Ask your hosting company to use Sql Server 2008 (or choose another host which does)

2) Use DateTime columns instead of Date

Comment: superb, I used `datetime` instead. will it give the same result ?

Answer (score 8):

[DATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) is a new datatype introduced in 2008. It is not available in 2005.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Other Version `SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()) AS DATETIME)`

Answer (score 1):

Change your database to use Datetime instead of Date.  That column type is supported in SQL Server 2005, whereas Date isn't.

Answer (score 0):

In 2005 run every time as 12:00 AM, this will allow time dimensions to match.

to strip off the "time" use something like this:

```
CAST(CONVERT(varchar(20), enteredDate, 101) AS DateTime) AS 'enterDate'
```

It will result with your time value being 12:00:00 AM which is default and you could consider effectively as `null`.